# Extracting elements from a nested list?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm working on a homework set and I need some help. I have a list that looks like this:

```
list = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
```

The problem is asking me to use list slicing to extract the last element of the nested list. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not use list as a variable name as it is a keyword in python

Answer (score 2):

```
list_1 = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
new_list = [elem[-1] for elem in list_1 if isinstance(elem, list)]
print(new_list )
```

Output:

```
[4]
```

For getting the last element of a list please refer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-get-the-last-element-of-list/).

For list comprehension, see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension-and-slicing/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get one element, then you just need to get the index of that element. In this case the external list has 4 elements:
`Index    0 1   2   3`
`Value    1 2 [3,4] 5`

The internal list has 2 elements:
`Index    0  1`
`Value    3  4`

So what you need to do is get the index of the internal list, `2`, and the index of the last element in the internal list `1` or `-1` (index `-1` always gets the last element in a list):

`element = list[2][1]`

Note: `list` is a reserved keyword in python so do not use it for variable naming.